Measurability of a set where a Measurable Sequence of functions converges to a measurable function
Given the definition of a measurable set in the picture Definition, if we have a sequence $\{f_n\}$ of nonnegative measurable functions that converges to a measurable function f pointwise almost everywhere on $X$, is the set $$X_0=\{x \in X:\{f_n(x)\} \text{ converges to f pointwise}\}$$ measurable? Is my argument correct:
Since $X_0=\{x \in X: f(x)=\lim_{n→∞}f_n(x)\}$ where $0\leq \lim_{n→∞}f_n(x)\leq∞$, then by the definition in the picture, $X_0$ is measurable. That is I am letting $f(x)=f$ and $\lim_{n→∞}f_n(x)=c$ where $0\leq c\leq∞$.

Your argument is incorrect because $c$ depends of $x$.

\begin{align}
X_0 &= \left\{ x \in X : \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = f(x) \right\} \\[1mm]
&= \{x \in X : \forall k \in \Bbb Z^+ \ \exists N \in \Bbb Z^+ \ \forall n \in \Bbb Z^+ \ (n \geq N \implies |f_n(x)-f(x)| < 1/k)\} \\
&= \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \bigcup_{N=1}^\infty \bigcap_{n=N}^\infty \{x \in X :  |f_n(x)-f(x)| < 1/k\}.
\end{align}
Now, since each function $|f_n-f|$ is measurable, each set $\{x \in X :  |f_n(x)-f(x)| < 1/k\}$ is measurable. Hence, $X_0$ is measurable.
